# Who is the synonym, and who is the target?

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

Let's assume I found that tags [a](/questions/tagged/a) and [b](/questions/tagged/b) are synonyms. Now let's assume that tag [a](/questions/tagged/a) is much more popular. Therefore, I am still assuming, tag [a](/questions/tagged/a) should be maintained while tag [b](/questions/tagged/b) should be the synonym. For example, [java](/questions/tagged/java) should stay the main tag in Stack Overflow, while it should have [openjdk](/questions/tagged/openjdk) as a synonym. And not the other way around.

Now let's take a case where I gained 5 points at tag [b](/questions/tagged/b), but didn't yet earn it in tag [a](/questions/tagged/a). So I can suggest [a](/questions/tagged/a) to be a synonym of [b](/questions/tagged/b), and not the other way around, which makes no sense. Is there any way to create a synonym in the other direction where I don't have the enough scoring? Is there any way to flip the synonym and the target, to not ending up with tags such as [openjdk](/questions/tagged/openjdk)(just an example of course)?

p.s.

Of course if I have the reputation to make tag synonym, I have the reputation to edit questions. So I can simply add the tag where I need it. But I don't think it is the right approach, as those questions might already have 5 tags in them, and giving up on tags just for suggesting a synonym looks weird to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Post a question on the site's own Meta (not here, we're the networkwide Meta) to ask for a synonym request. ♦ moderators are automatically notified of new questions on their meta, so you have a good chance (if the request is justified) that it's carried out quickly. The voting process on synonym requests is rather slow.

For examples, see various [synonym-request](/questions/tagged/synonym-request) questions on this site (when it pertains to synonymizing two Meta Stack Exchange tags) or on other Meta sites in the network.

Comment: This answer works. I published a post, and got what I wanted. But till I think that it makes sense to allow suggesting tag synonym from a tag that I don't have enough score into a tag that I do. I think it will decrease friction.